# How can I filter a collection so I get only the rows where the value of a fields is not null?

Tags: c#

I have a call to GetData() that returns a collection of TQ:

```
IList<TQ> tq = _questionService.GetData();

public class TQ
{
    // Index
    public int i { get; set; }
    // Text
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

How can I filter what's in tq and make another list where text is not null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_questionService.GetData().Where(x => x.text != null);
```

You might be interested in reading up on [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397927.aspx), it will be one of your most important tools in C# development.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LINQ you can use

```
var newList = tq.Where(p => p.text != null).ToList()
```

else something like that

```
var newList = new List<TQ>();

foreach(var element in tq) {
    if (element.text != null) {
        newList.Add(element);
    }
}
```